# Selenium Grid2: Timeout on requesting a new session

Tags: selenium

I have been hitting this issue from Selenium Grid2 since 2.41.0 or earlier. Currently I am using 2.44.0. The way I set up was having a node (running on Windows7) with maxSession to be 16, and a hub running on Linux. After the setup is done, I can see from the Grid/console that there were 16 icons available, which is expected. But when I kicked out tests which require more than 6 browser instances (in this case, Chrome browser), and I can see from the grid/console there were 6 icons grayed-out, and some message saying that there were also some "requests waiting for a slot to be free": https://selenium.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=63970009000&name=Screen+Shot+2014-11-13+at+12.10.46+PM.png&token=ABZ6GAd1E0jC2GEYFnemYyFfc8n9RA9uYQ%3A1416429465010&inline=1.

And from the log, here I found:
WebDriverException: Message: Error forwarding the new session Request timed out waiting for a node to become available.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are configuration options for max instances of each browser type as well as the overall max number of instances.

Could your configuration be limiting the number of Chromes to 6?